# Examples of Binary Functions that Yield Regular Graphs with Invertible Adjacency Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

> **Question:**
>
> What are, provided their existence, examples of functions $f$ with the following properties:
>   
>   \begin{align}f:& \ \mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\ni(i,j)&\mapsto\  \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ \beta\in\lbrace 0,1\rbrace\\
> &f(i,i)&=\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ 0\\
> &f(i,j)&=\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\ f(j,i)\\
> &\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}{f(i,j)}&=\quad k\in\mathbb{N}\quad \forall n\ge n_0\ge k\\
> &\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}{f(i,j)}&=\quad k\in\mathbb{N}\quad \forall n\ge n_0\ge k\\
> &F\in\lbrace0,1\rbrace^{n\times n},\ 1\le i,j \le n,\ F_{ij}=f(i,j)&\implies\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \ |F|\ne 0\end{align}
>   The calculation of $f(i,j)$ must not depend on $n$ but would ideally be parameterized by $k\in\mathbb{N}$
>
> In reply to @PuckRombach's comment:
>   Another restriction is that, given $k$ the $f(i,j)$ must yield matrices with the described properties for all $n\ge n_0\ge k$

Comment: These exist for every $n$: if you take a matrix that has 0s on the diagonal and 1s everywhere else it is invertible. Does your question come down to: how many matrices in $GL(n,\mathbb{Z}_2)$ have constant row/column sums and 0s on the diagonal?

Comment: @PuckRombach your first example amounts to $k=n$, which implies a dependency of $k$ on $n$, a case that I thought I had ruled out; I will edit accordingly. To your second question: I am not so much interested in the number of such matrices or in concrete examples of such matrices, but rather in functions that yield such matrices.

Comment: It would be $k=n-1$, but we can also let every column have $k$ 1s starting below the diagonal, for example. Isn't the matrix equivalent to the kind of function you want?

Comment: @PuckRombach Initially I would be happy with a function that works for $k=2$ and arbitrary $n\ge 4$

Comment: Does $f(i,j)=\begin{cases} 1,\;\; \mbox{ if } 1\leq i-j \pmod{n} \leq k,\\ 0,\;\; \mbox{otherwise,} \end{cases}$ do the trick?

Comment: @PuckRombach I guess I have already mentioned that these cyclically wrapped band matrices don't always work. See my question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/318761/explanation-for-dependency-of-solvability-of-a-system-of-linear-equations-on-a-n take $k=2$ and $n$ even

Comment: In that case I think you should rephrase the question here to include explicitly the properties that you need your matrix to have.